# Define multi level spring application.yml hierarchy

Tags: spring, spring-boot

> However, the most important profiles-related feature that Spring Boot brings is profile-specific properties files. These have to be named in the format application-{profile}.properties.
>
> Spring Boot will automatically load the properties in an application.properties file for all profiles, and the ones in profile-specific .properties files only for the specified profile.
>
> -- from https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles

So this is possible:

application.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
```

application-dev.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://development.server:14331;databaseName=Dev;
```

When you use the dev profile, Spring would load the 'driver-class-name' from application.yml

---

I am searching for something like this:

application-dev-myconfig.yml:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    username: myVeryOwnDbUser
    password: myVeryOwnPassword
```

Now if you use the dev-myconfig profile it should take the 'url' from dev profile and the 'driver-class-name' from the default profile.

Is it possible to have another level, like this? Or how would you do that?

Thanks and have a good Day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can have more than one active spring profile and that would solve your problem.
In your case `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev,dev-myconfig`

Comment: hmm, better than nothing. But can it be a little more automated? So i always have to remember to add the dev profile everywhere i want to build it :/

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question, and after conducting some research, I didn't find out a simple way to create inheritance in property files.

Here is what I came to:

1. You can specify more than one profile when you start your app, and each next profile overrides properties from the previous one. This is exactly what is recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68409008/6933090).
2. You can define defaults in the root property file (`application.yaml`) using [multi-documents file spring feature](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.multi-document):

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
---
spring:
  config:
    activate:
      on-profile:
        - "dev-myconfig1"
        - "dev-myconfig2"
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:sqlserver://development.server:14331;databaseName=Dev;
```

Then if you run your app with either "dev-myconfig1" or "dev-myconfig2" profiles you will get `spring.datasource.url` and you can also override it if you need in your `application-dev-myconfig1/2.yaml`.